# Is there a proper way to "break" out of a switch script and remain in the procedure other than wrapping in a loop?

Tags: tcl

I was trying to not repeat the same code in different switch blocks and could not figure out how to break out a switch script except to return and exit the procedure.

My question is, Is wrapping the switch in a while loop simply to break, when desired, a terrible thing to do and is there a better way?

It took me awhile, but I realize that a break is not necessary because could set variable in the catch and test outside it to determine when the rest of the code under opt_2 is run (as in the second code example below); but having a break is more clear, especially when the real code is a bit more involved than this example.

Thank you.

```
% proc SwitchBreak {condition valid} {
  set ui_state 1
  while { 1 } {
    switch -- $condition {
       opt_1 {
         chan puts stdout opt_1
       } opt_2 {
         chan puts stdout opt_2
         if { [info exists ui_state] && $ui_state == $valid } {
           if { [catch { throw {Database Error} {Failed to Write} } result]} {
             chan puts stdout "${result}. Rolled back"
             set rv 1
             set response {Operation Failed}
             break
           }
         }
         chan puts stdout {Opt_1 code to run only when\
            no valid ui_state or valid state succeeds.}
         set rv 0
         set response {Successful write.}
       } opt_3 {
         chan puts stdout opt_3
       } default {
         chan puts stdout opt_4
       }
    }
    break
  }
  chan puts stdout {Code after the switch.}
  chan puts stdout "rv: $rv; response: $response"
}
% SwitchBreak opt_2 1
opt_2
Failed to Write. Rolled back
Code after the switch.
rv: 1; response: Operation Failed
% SwitchBreak opt_2 0 
opt_2
Opt_1 code to run only when no valid ui_state or valid state succeeds.
Code after the switch.
rv: 0; response: Successful write.
```

No loop, no break.

```
proc SwitchBreak {condition valid} {
  set ui_state 1
    switch -- $condition {
       opt_1 {
         chan puts stdout opt_1
       } opt_2 {
         chan puts stdout opt_2
         set rv 0
         if { [info exists ui_state] && $ui_state == $valid } {
           if { [catch { throw {Database Error} {Failed to Write} } result]} {
             chan puts stdout "${result}. Rolled back"
             set rv 1
             set response {Operation Failed}
           }
         }
         if { $rv == 0 } {
           chan puts stdout {Opt_1 code to run only when\
              no valid ui_state or valid state succeeds.}    
           set response {Successful write.}
         }
       } opt_3 {
         chan puts stdout opt_3
       } default {
         chan puts stdout opt_4
       }
    } 
  chan puts stdout {Code after the switch.}
  chan puts stdout "rv: $rv; response: $response"
}

% % 
% Switch opt_2 1
opt_2
Failed to Write. Rolled back
Code after the switch.
rv: 1; response: Operation Failed
% SwitchBreak opt_2 0
opt_2
Opt_1 code to run only when no valid ui_state or valid state succeeds.
Code after the switch.
rv: 0; response: Successful write.
```

Comment: Not sure about your case, but in some languages, an effective way among accepted practices to handle complex jumps is to wrap portions in function calls.

Comment: Just lurking to see what sort of help you receive. Other than a few trivial `expect` scripts I haven't used Tcl for anything as complicated as what you're doing in more than 30 years. I'm curious if you're doing this in the context of the `expect` program or independent of it? And if the latter, why since there are almost certainly better options?

Comment: SQLite has bindings for many popular languages, including Go and Python (I've used SQLite with both). My recommendation is to use whichever of those languages you prefer rather than the Tcl binding.

Comment: @KurtisRader Thank you for the recommendation. I've never used either of those languages; and don't have a whole lot of real programming experience overall. Nonetheless (and please know that I'm not trying to be rude or start an argument),  I've come to like Tcl quite a bit; and the more I learn about it the more I like it. If I were a young man interested in computer science for a career, I'd be studying the Tcl and SQLite source code.

Comment: If you are an inexperienced programmer learning Tcl isn't very useful. You should only learn it if you absolutely have to. Such as if you intend to contribute changes to the SQLite project. Investing in learning a modern language like Go, Rust, etc. (all of which have SQLite bindings) will be far more useful to you in the long run. Tcl was created in 1986; ten years after I started to learn how to program. It has many flaws and is now used only in a few niche applications such as tkinter and SQLite. Again, you're better off learning a different language.

Comment: I don't know about Tcl flaws and the programming industry, but to be fair to Tcl it must still be active.  For example,  the second edition of [Ousterhout's book](https://www.tcltk-book.com/), (Tcl's founder) on Tcl/Tk was published in 2010 ; Ashock Nadkarni wrote a [larger text on just Tcl](https://www.magicsplat.com/ttpl/index.html) in 2017; and there was an [update to 8.6.14](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Tcl/) March 25th of this year. It may be a niche in the respect that job postings mentioning Tcl appear to be for computer geniuses only and not novices like me.

Comment: @Gary I think it's fair to say you can ignore the  "I don't know the answer to your issue, use a library that I know something about" stuff. While I'm also no expert for tcl, I would look into [coroutines](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/coroutine), since tcl natively hosts an event-loop I'm unsure if you actually need to [go loopy](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Going+Loopy+with+Coroutines) with it.

Comment: @Gary FORTRAN and COBOL are still active (I used to be proficient in those languages). That doesn't mean I would recommend a new programmer expend the effort to learn those languages. :-) It has nothing to do with Tcl being for "computer geniuses only and not novices". Tcl is simply an interesting language, intended for a specific purpose (embedded in applications as a way to control their behavior), and never gained widespread use as a general purpose language. It's certainly not dead but it seems to me the O.P. would be better off interacting with SQLite using another language.

Comment: @Thingamabobs What will be interesting is how long it takes someone to answer the O.P.'s question. Which is why I am lurking and encouraging the O.P. to use a different language binding to interact with SQLite. Also, I'm not suggesting the O.P. use a "library that I know something about". I am suggesting they use a different language binding. Tcl is simply one, of many, language bindings for the SQLite library. Albeit a binding treated by  the project as special due to its use in its unit tests.

Comment: `switch` is not a loop, so of course loop control constructs like `break` don't work with it. Maybe a bit less code, a bit more explaining what you're trying to accomplish (Not how; what)?

Comment: @KurtisRader It won't be the only question with no answers on SO. If O.P wanted to work with a huge data-base and had performance issues and tcl simply comes to it's limit since it isn't the core of tcl to work with huge data bases and someone recommends to use python for it, it would be reasonable to do this. Since O.P isn't hitting any limit and just want to advance in a to O.P. already known tech, it is simply unreasonable to suggest a different language in this context.

Comment: (I'd much rather use tcl to work with a sqlite database than python)

Comment: @Shawn The O.P.'s code uses `break` inside a `switch` inside a `while` loop. In many (most?) languages that `break` would terminate the `while` loop. Is that not true of Tcl? Again, I say this as someone who was a minimally competent Tcl programmer three decades ago and has only used it for scripting in the `expect` tool since then. The O.P. also seems to have adequately explained what they are trying to do. So I'm a wee bit confused by your comment.

Comment: @KurtisRader Yes, it would break out of the loop. But OP's goal seems to be ending the body of a switch case early. The question is, *what* are they doing that makes them want to do this? There might be a better way to lay out their code, but need a higher level picture of the goal to say for sure. Basically, I'm wondering if this is an XY problem.

Comment: *Is there a proper way to "break" out of a switch script and remain in the procedure other than wrapping in a loop?* In my opinion that actually calls for coroutines, preserving the context while returning. But again, I'm not an expert in tcl and can't provide any code solution to this.

Comment: `catch throw` seems like an expensive way to set a variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is *legal* in that you can write it and it will execute correctly, it seems very ugly to me; a simple `if`...`else` would appear to be able to express the intent while actually being clearer. I would even go as far as to say that I would expect that to normally be true.

```
# Just the bit inside the switch case
chan puts stdout opt_2
if {
    [info exists ui_state] && $ui_state == $valid
    && [catch {
        # This is a stand-in for something real, right? Right?
        throw {Database Error} "Failed to Write"
    } result]
} then {
    chan puts stdout "${result}. Rolled back"
    set rv 1
    set response "Operation Failed"
} else {
    chan puts stdout "Opt_1 code to run only when\
        no valid ui_state or valid state succeeds."
    set rv 0
    set response "Successful write."
}
```

Would there be a case where doing this convoluted thing with a run-once `while` is best? I doubt it... but never say never.

---

A run-once `for` would be slightly better, provided you put `break` in the increment clause. Like that, it's clearer at the top what you are doing.

Or you could use `try` with an `on break` clause.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the throw is a stand-in for a transaction of a fairly simple upsert.  An `if` is used in the second example but not like in yours. I guess I was focused on under what conditions to perform the database transaction and failed to see that the success of that transaction could be part of that single `if`. If the script of the `if` is more complicated, I'll try the `try` with `on break` or just make it a separate procedure; and avoid any form of run-once loop.

Comment: I didn't know that there was an optional `then` to an `if` statement. I generally reference two hard-copy texts on Tcl, rather than being on-line; and, if either writes of it, I missed it. It's clear on the Tcl manual page, though.

Comment: Well, [the online docs](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/) and manual pages (both come from the same source) are definitive references. Books are learning material, but not normative.